# when should i destroy the token

Tags: javascript, express, jwt, token

### I have many questions about token

1. should I create the token when the user login and register or (login only)?
2. should I save the token in local storage?
3. should I send the token after every request user made?
4. should I destroy the token after logout only?
5. after user register he/she will have the token here I should save the token   in local storage and after he/she will log in should I replace the token   because he/she will have a new one
   should I destroy the token and make a new one and replace it in local storage?
6. last question how can I use the token to let the user login immediately after he/she register?

### sorry for tired you guys but these questions come to my mind when I try to make authentication stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- login only

2- no  "If you store it inside localStorage, it's accessible by any script inside your page (which is as bad as it sounds as an XSS attack can let an external attacker get access to the token)."   instead you can save it in  an HttpOnly cookie

3- yes and you have to validate it also

4- it depends if you need to save it for history and revision user transactions so save it if you don't so delete it

5- you have to redirect user to your app in case of he has a valid token so he can't open login page if he has valid token, in order to login again he have to log out, also what if he logged again should I remove old token ?  DON'T because maybe he opened your app from other device

6- return token to front end save that token then redirect user to the app page not the login.

Regarding to the main question header, when you delete token?

1- on logout

2- you can make daily check ( job or from code  ) to find the expired tokens and delete it.

3- on receive an expired token in any web service delete it and redirect user to login page

Comment: Just google your second answer..

Answer (score 0):

Important topic, I suggest you spend a little time reading about it, but for starters here are some quick answers:

1. Mainly login, you could also make the registration confirmation link set it somehow, but that depends on the workflow, it's enough to have the user login after registration.
2. No, not safe, it should be only in memory. (in a store for example)
3. Yes, you can set the authentication token in the header for each call.
4. Logout, also depending on the safety level you require, you can set some expire date on it just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I think point two is not correct, if you saved it in memory so each time user refresh the page the token will be removed and he has to login again !! .

Comment: to 2.: a secure HttpOnly cookie would also be an option.